# Javascript Delete row with checkbox

Tags: javascript

Hi i'm a beginner and  I'm trying to do a simple CRUD Car apps but i cannot delete row with my function deleteRow().

I've create a function call deleteRow i add a checkbox in every row with the createElement method and i'm setting the Id attribute using the setAttribute() method.In my function i'm trying to get to the checkbox to see if its checked and if so using the deleteRow method to delete the row.

```js
function addRow() {
  /* check if its empty */
  var brandValue = document.getElementById("brand").value;
  var modelValue = document.getElementById("model").value;
  if (brandValue == "" || modelValue == "") {
    return alert("Make sure you enter a brand and a model!")
  }

  /* Add a row */
  "use strict";
  var table = document.getElementById("table");
  var row = document.createElement("tr");
  var td1 = document.createElement("td");
  var td2 = document.createElement("td");
  var td3 = document.createElement("INPUT");

  td3.setAttribute("type", "checkbox");
  td3.setAttribute("id", "cb");

  td1.innerHTML = document.getElementById("brand").value;
  td2.innerHTML = document.getElementById("model").value;

  row.appendChild(td1);
  row.appendChild(td2);
  row.appendChild(td3);

  table.children[0].appendChild(row);

  document.getElementById('brand').value = "";
  document.getElementById('model').value = "";
}

var temp = 1;

function deleteRow() {
  for (var j = temp - 2; j >= 0; j--) {

    if (document.table.cb[j].checked) {
      document.getElementById("table").deleteRow(j + 1);

    }
  }

}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="brand" placeholder="Add a brand">
<input type="text" id="model" placeholder="Add a Model">
<button type="button" onClick="addRow()" id="add">Update</button>
<button type="button" onClick="deleteRow()" id="delete">Delete</button>

<table id="table">
  <div class="tableDiv">
    <tr>
      <th>Brands</th>
      <th>Models</th>
      <th>Select</th>
    </tr>
  </div>
</table>
```

Right now nothing happen when i'm trying to delete and i have nothing in the browser console.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: what are you doing with `temp`?

Comment: Also, every time you add a checkbox, you are using the same id "cb". Each element on your page needs a different id. You may want to add the position that the checkbox is in to the id. Such as "cb_0", "cb_1", "cb_2". Since they all will then have different ids, you will be able to select which specific checkboxes that you want to delete.

Comment: Your table is invalid - you don't close the div tag, but more importantly, div are not allowed to be children of table

Comment: Hi Pete so i should never have a div in a table but i can have a table in a div ?

Comment: yes you can pretty much have anything in a div (apart from orphaned `tr`s like in your code!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```js
const $brand = document.getElementById("brand")
const $model = document.getElementById("model")

const $table = document.getElementById("table")

function addRow() {
  /* check if its empty */
  if ($brand.value == "" || $model.value == "") {
    return alert("Make sure you enter a brand and a model!")
  }  
  
  let $row = document.createElement("tr");
  let $td1 = document.createElement("td");
  let $td2 = document.createElement("td");
  let $td3 = document.createElement("input");

  $td3.setAttribute("type", "checkbox");

  $td1.innerHTML = $brand.value;
  $td2.innerHTML = $model.value;

  $row.appendChild($td1);
  $row.appendChild($td2);
  $row.appendChild($td3);

  $table.children[0].appendChild($row);

  $brand.value = "";
  $model.value = "";
}

function deleteRow() {
  let checkboxs = $table.querySelectorAll("input[type='checkbox']:checked")
  checkboxs.forEach(checkbox => checkbox.parentElement.remove())
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="brand" placeholder="Add a brand"></input>
<input type="text" id="model" placeholder="Add a Model"></input>
<button type="button" onClick="addRow()" id="add">Update</button>
<button type="button" onClick="deleteRow()" id="delete">Delete</button>
</div>
<table id="table">
  <div class="tableDiv" <tr>
    <th>Brands</th>
    <th>Models</th>
    <th>Select</th>
    </tr>
  </div>
</table>
```

Comment: This work great ! However i'm  really noob so i would like to make sure i understand properly so for the delteRow function when you do  checkboxs.forEach(checkbox => checkbox.parentElement.remove()) it means you check all the checkbox one by one and when they are checked you remove the parent element which is the row it self (tr)? I will start using Const and let properly  but can you explain me whats is the benefit of using the $ before setting the variable name?  Thanks for your help its really aprreciated

Comment: 1. querySelectorAll() will select all elements inside $table element with this query "input[type='checkbox']:checked", this mean all inputs checkeds.

2.i assigning on checkboxs variable with querySelectorAll () elements obtained, then i using forEach function to iterate every item using checkbox key for each element.

Comment: 3.for each checkbox element i quering for his parentElement, this mean will select <tr> tag (this content have 3 <td> tags, all the row), then y using remove() function to remove the element quered.

4. i using $ before some element just because i got used to it from jquery to indicate to me i targeting some element, just is my self convention.

Answer (score 0):

`for (var j = temp - 2; j >= 0; j--) {` this loop never starts due to `temp` being `1`.

1 - 2 = -1 so the loop condition (`j >= 0`) is never true.

Answer (score 0):

Your main mistake is that you don't need to iterate anything, you can select the checked elements directly. 
Try using document.querySelector("#table input[type='checkbox']:checked")

Another thing is that now you are assigning the same id to multiple elements. This should not be done, it can lead to unexpected behavior. Consider using class or custom attribute instead

Comment: do i really need the ID to delete the row ? if so i will have to add an different ID for each row that i create right ?

Comment: No, you only need to select the checked inputs. Then you can select their parent with .parentElement. Then you will have selected the tr, containing the checked checkbox

Answer (score 0):

```
let checkboxes = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"]:checked');

checkboxes.forEach(checkbox => checkbox.parentElement.parentElement.remove());
```

Comment: Please, avoid code-only answers. Future readers will be grateful to see explained _why_ this answers the question instead of having to infer it from the code.